# I have two css classes and i want to ignore the css of internal class?

Tags: css

```
<div class="style1"> 
<h3 class="style2">Text</h3>
</div>
```

I want to impose style1 on h3 or whatever comes in inside the div with class style1

Comment: What is your current CSS? are you just looking for: .style1 h3{}

Comment: can you explain clearly with your expected output?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking but it sounds like `.style1 * {}` is what you are after. Please try to elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Examples would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.style1, .style1 h3 {
   color: red;
   font-size: 2em;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Or if you have a style like **h3.style2 {}**
just add importatn to the style rules wiwant to overwrite.

Like:

```
.style1, .style1 h3 {
   color: red !important;
   font-size: 2em;
   margin: 0 !important;
   padding: 0;
}
```

or what ever styling you want.

You can also do that with **.style1 * {}** and using !important to every rule you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

`.style1 > * {}` Will apply to any element found directly inside.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/b2hn989d/